# Opayo - How to handle timeouts?

Tags: opayo

I currently manage an integration into Opayo Direct (v4.00). We send requests to Opayo, which most of the time work fine, but occasionally they time out (Our timeout limit is currently set to 20s, which is *ages* for a consumer to wait).

Does anyone know of a way to either:

1. Retry the payment request without double charging the consumer? or,
2. Send a follow up request to get the status of the submitted payment?

For 2. it looks like you need valid transaction identifier from Opayo, which of course we won't have as the request has timed out.

I can't see any mention of idempotency or guidance for what to do in this situation, even in their most recent API specification (PI integration).

Has anyone come up with a workable solution for this problem, other than change provider?

Comment: Where are you getting the timeout?  Is it upon the initial submission to Opayo or the bit where you send the customer to the 3ds page?  Within Direct, payment shouldn't ever be taken until you received your response and validated it - I believe the validation process is the bit where it "takes" the money (submitting the validation twice will void the payment though)

Comment: Opayo occasionally have timeouts, and they can happen anywhere (i.e initial submission or the challenge response, if the consumer needs challenged).

I just think it's pretty poor that they don't have any sort of resiliency strategy for network timeouts or disconnections etc, even in their new API.

Comment: I've since highlighted this issue with their priority support team. They say they'll pass it on to their product development teams ...

It's affecting one in every few thousand transactions of ours normally, however I'm worried about the times where there might be an actual network blip somewhere..